# Python Почему не работает код

Tags: python

Написал код который считает количество цифр в списке. Но он не работает, что я делаю не так? Вот сам код:

```
p2 = list(p1)   #Ввод превращает в список

count1 = [0, 0]  #Создаем спиок для подсчета количества цифр

#Цикл, если в спике есть "1" то count1[0] увел. на 1, тоже самое с 2, если ввели другой символ, то его пропускаем
for ans in count1:    
    if ans == 1:  
        count1[1] += 1
    elif ans == 2:
        count1[2] += 1
    else:
        continue

print(p2)
print(count1)
```

допустим написали мы в ввод: 11212
и он выводит:

```
['1', '1', '2', '1', '2']
[0, 0]
```

но должен выводить так:

```
['1', '1', '2', '1', '2']
[3, 2]
```

3 означает что там единиц 3шт, а двоек 2шт

Comment: Храните значения отдельно. Инкрементируйте нужное.  Конкатенация и добавление `:` - только при выводе на экран.

Comment: если честно, я ничего не понял, можете примером кода ответить

Comment: почитайте Python для детей. Самоучитель по программированию
АВТОР
Джейсон Бриггс

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы пускаете цикл не по тому списку.
   Список `count1` у вас является выходными данными, а список `p2` - входными (сами же это и написали). Таким образом вам нужно пускать цикл не по `count1` а по `p2`.
2. Более того, вы в примере указали такой входной список: `['1', '1', '2', '1', '2']`. В этом списке элементы типа `string` (строка), а у вас в коде вы сравниваете строку с числом: `if ans == 1: # ans - строка, 1 - число.`
3. Так же не стоит создавать 2 переменны `p1` и `p2` ради 1 ввода. Достаточно написать так:
   `p1 = input() # Получаем входные данные`

   `p1 = p1.list() # Преобразовываем в список`

Или же:

```
p1 = input().list()
```

4. И наконец, нумерация элементов в списках начинается с 0, а не с 1. Таким образом у вас нет элемента с индексом `2` в списке `count1`.

В итоге вот как должен выглядеть код:

```
p1 = input().list() # Получаем входные данные и сразу преобразовываем их в список

count1 = [0, 0]  #Создаем спиок для подсчета количества цифр

#Цикл, если в спике **p1** есть "1" то count1[0] увел. на 1, тоже самое с 2, если ввели другой символ, то его пропускаем

for ans in count1:    
    if int(ans) == 1:  # т.к. все элементы в списке типа string, а сравниваем мы с числом, пробразовываем элемент в тип integer.
        count1[0] += 1 # Нумерация в списках начинается с 0.
    elif int(ans) == 2:
        count1[1] += 1
    else:
        continue

print(p2)
print(count1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно решить так:

```py
a = {'1': 0, '2': 0}
for i in input():
    if i in a:
        a[i] += 1           
print([a['1'], a['2']])
```

а можно так:

```py
from collections import Counter
a = Counter(input())
print([a['1'], a['2']])
```